# How to pass option key and value as an object from jsp to Struts 2 action class?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have a scenario where I want to send `SelectOption` object to action class on change of struts jQuery dropdown, but it seems like it`s not possible.

Is there any workaround or any way out to get this done?

**JSP code:**

```jsp
<sj:select href = "%{fetchCountry}" 
             id = "country" 
 onChangeTopics = "reloadsecondlist" 
           name = "country" 
          value = "%{country}"
           list = "countryList" 
        listKey = "key" 
      listValue = "value" 
    emptyOption = "false"
      headerKey = "-1" 
    headerValue = "Please Select a Country" />
```

**Note:** DropDown consist of list of `SelectOption` object.

**Update:**

```jsp
<s:url id="fetchState" action="json" method="fetchState" namespace="/"/>

<sj:select href = "%{fetchState}" 
             id = "stateID" 
        formIds = "formSelectReload"
   reloadTopics = "reloadsecondlist" 
           name = "state" 
          value = "%{state}" 
           list = "stateMap" 
        listKey = "key" 
      listValue = "value" 
    emptyOption = "false" 
      headerKey = "-1" 
    headerValue = "Please Select a State" />
```

Comment: What is it SelectOption object?

Comment: SelectOtion is a class having members Long key, String value.
In my case i used the object of this class to populate countryList like :
List<SelectOption> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
SelectOption so = new SelectOption(1L,"India");
countryList .add(so);

Comment: Is this list populated? Also I want to see the reload topic handler source code.

Comment: yes this list **countryList** is populated in struts action and i`m using it in Jsp as you can see in above code. I have updated the question for reload topic handler.

Comment: Define it's not possible. Which error do you get ? And what exactly do you want to achieve, sending value from select1 to load select2 based on that ?

Comment: @AshutoshRanjan You can listen on topic change event and send key/value pair via ajax. The action code/and config is required to populate with parameters

Comment: @Roman C You are right, i can do that and i know how to do that. But I was wondering if it is possible to send whole object instead sending key/value pair independently. This is the main reason i raised this question. In Wicket framework onchange event of DropDown  you can get the required object directly, and i`m trying to do the same for my struts2 project.

Comment: @AshutoshRanjan What do you mean to send the whole object, the object could be serialized and sent, and consumer has to deserialize it before the using. You can send the object serialized as key/value pair, there're different serializeres exist. I don't understand the question, because it's probably off-topic.